# Whatsapp message requests without Selenium

Tags: selenium, automation, request, message, whatsapp

Simple project. Send, receive or generally simplify your life by automating messages. For example, I need to send "Happy new Year!" message to certain group of people. Heck, I'll go step further and make  programmable messages: `"Happy new year, {name}!"` .

But there is a constraint, I can't use Selenium based api nor webhook. That'd be too easy!

My question is, is there any free tool or api in any programming language that can send, receive WhatsApp messages?

To have an idea of the project, here is a little sketch. Note: I'm not the best designer.

[image]

Comment: TO send Scheduled message you can use away message https://faq.whatsapp.com/smba/account-and-profile/using-away-messages/?lang=en

Comment: @bZezzz I do not want to use WhatsApp's app in any way.

Comment: WhatsApp API is limited to business. So... But interesting question.

Comment: May it help https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=XXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: Again, this requires me to have my browser open, and manually log in.

Comment: Pywhakit ? https://pypi.org/project/pywhatkit/

Comment: I'll look at it

Comment: Or symply login one time to whatsapp web, then `webbrowser.open('https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=' +phone_no + '&text=' + parsed_message)` with python do the tricks, but not really clean, but one thing, without API access, you must be connected to WhatsApp web at least one time, because of QR code security.

Comment: Yes, that kinda works. But I just don't like waiting for the browser to load and send it. Thanks for the help @Bzezzz. I'll wait a week, maybe someone will suggest, if not I'll have to use Selenium :(

Comment: You can do that in headless mode as well..

Comment: What's headless mode, can please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest this one, which I used.  You can send and receive messages and send stickers and images.

Here is the Github location: https://github.com/open-wa/wa-automate-python

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest this one, which I made. You can send messages, files and images.

Here is the Github location: https://github.com/ammarayh89/whatsapp-web-api-using-python

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks

Answer (score -1):

After trying many APIs I decided to go with Twilio's WhatsApp API. Of course, you will have to pay a small amount, but **$0.005** per message is basically free. You will get 200 messages per dollar.

If you are interested see this [link](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/send-and-receive-media-messages-whatsapp-python).

But before that, I am planning to try this one: https://github.com/allburov/whatsapp-http-api